# Illustrator: Alt+Click in Pathfinder not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Unite, minus front, intersect and exclude all work fine. But once I'm *alt+clicking* (on unite, minus front, etc), nothing is happening. Like, my 2 grouped shapes just stay the same. For e.g. when I *alt+click* on Unite, it doesn't even give me the result that clicking on Unite alone would give me.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. Alt+click does seem to work just fine.  Maybe check using some simple shapes.  Do you perhaps have some effects on some of the objects? Maybe check the appearance panel just in case.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> clicking a **Pathfinder Panel** button essentially removes the "expand" aspect of the operations.

In other words, the *operations **is** still performed*. However, nothing is *expanded*. So, you *see* your original shapes outlines. The *interaction* between these shapes should react as expected using the pathfinder operation.

[image]

You *will* still see the highlighted outlines of the original shapes. 
But how/where the shapes interact will change.

The advantage of <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-clicking is that you can move things around and the operation is still "live".... Note below the *interaction* between the shape is a result of the Pathfinder operation...

[image]

After <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-clicking you can use `Object > Expand Appearance` and you get the standard Pathfinder result...

[image]

---

This is true for *most* of the operations. (I haven't tested each and every one).

Unite gives the same result with or without the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key. The only difference is that with <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> the operation is "live", allowing you to move the objects independently if needed.

[image]